# DropDownlist value is inserted as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to insert value of dropdownlist in db but instead of storing its selected value it is
storing this value `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]`.
Here is my code.
View:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.propertyType, (List<SelectListItem>) ViewData["property"])
```

Model:

```
   public string propertyType { get; set; }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditProfile()

    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Private Residence", Value = "Private Residence" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Office", Value = "Office" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Place of worship", Value = "Place of worship" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Commercial Parking lot", Value = "Commercial Parking lot" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Retail", Value = "Retail" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Academic Institution", Value = "Academic Institution" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });
        ViewData["property"] = items;




        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult EditProfile(EditProfile edit)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Private Residence", Value = "Private Residence" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Office", Value = "Office" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Place of worship", Value = "Place of worship" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Commercial Parking lot", Value = "Commercial Parking lot" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Retail", Value = "Retail" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Academic Institution", Value = "Academic Institution" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });
        ViewData["property"] = items;
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>()
                    where q.Email == UserName
                    select q;
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var update in query)
            {

                update.contactNo = edit.contactNo;
                update.occupation = ViewData["property"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("","");

        Session.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: does your 'edit' object get proper values ?

Comment: yeah all edit objects are getting proper values except this dropdownlist value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is crazy:

```
update.occupation = ViewData["property"].ToString();
```

it should be:

```
update.occupation = edit.propertyType;
```

Answer (score 1):

I always try to avoid using ViewData or ViewBag. Try following for this porpose:

Create static class for all dropdowns:

```
public static class MyDrops
{

public static List<SelectListItem> GetList()
{
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Private Residence", Value = "Private Residence" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Office", Value = "Office" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Place of worship", Value = "Place of worship" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Commercial Parking lot", Value = "Commercial Parking lot" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Retail", Value = "Retail" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Academic Institution", Value = "Academic Institution" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });
return items;
}
}
```

Then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.propertyType, MyDrops.GetList())
```

Comment: How can i access MyDrops class in view?/

Comment: @Wasfa Just add namespace in View: using Projectname.FolderWhereClassSaved

Comment: I tried this one in view @using MvcMembership.Models.MyDrops but it is giving an error 'MvcMembership.Models.MyDrops' is a type not a namespace

Comment: @Wasfa Without MyDrops. Just: using MvcMembership.Models and in Dropdown MyDrops.GetList(). MyDrops and  GetList() should be static as in my example